# Button Onclick to Change Color Perm until MouseOver

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to figure this out. When a button has a "click" event, change both the "bgColor" property and the "bgcolor" variable to the appropriate color

so Far I Have

```
var heading, size = 1, color = "red", bgcolor = "white", fgcolor = "black";
```

But If i create a Function for Example `function onclicki()`, how would i make it so that the bgcolor perm stays for example red only if i click it, and if I do a mouseover it changes. So only Onclick it should stay Perm, thanks.

```
function onclicki()
         {

         document.bgColor="red"


         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
var heading,
    size = 1,
    color = "red",
    bgcolor = "white",
    fgcolor = "black";

//runs when you click the button
function onclicki(){
  document.bgColor = bgcolor = 'red';
}
//runs when you mouseover the button
function changeback(){
  document.bgColor = bgcolor = 'white';
}
```

```html
<button onclick='onclicki()' onmouseover='changeback()'>Press me, mouseout and then mouseover!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tobsta, why the single quotes?

Comment: @Sid It doesn't really matter, but I prefer single quotes because you don't have to hold shift while pressing the quotes key. (In other words it's just a tad faster to type)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/0j1me71m/2/

```
var div = document.getElementById( 'div' );
div.onclick = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};
div.onmouseover = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
};
```